# OpenAI Embeddings API: How do I extract the embedding vector from the response?

Tags: json, typescript, embedding, openai-api

Im transitioning from js to ts and experimenting with the embedding API of OpenAI.

My goal here is to get the array values of the "embedding" key from the JSON response & store it on a variable, simple as that, the problem is i haven't been able to actually do this since yesterday and im loosing my mind:

The code:

```
// Generate Embeddings
async function generateEmbed(text:string): Promise<void> {
  const url = 'https://api.openai.com/v1/embeddings';
  const model = 'text-embedding-ada-002'; // Replace with the ID of the model you want to use
  const input = text;
 
  const requestBody = {
    model,
    input
  };
  //
  //console.log(requestBody);
  //

  try {
    const API_KEY = 'XXXX-XXX-XXX-VALIDKEY'; // test purposes

    const response = await axios.post(url, requestBody, {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Authorization: `Bearer ${API_KEY}`
      }
    });

    const embedding: string = response.data[2].text;
    console.log('Result:', embedding);

  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}
```

This prints:

`TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'text')`

The example JSON response is:

```
{
    "object": "list",
    "data": [
        {
            "object": "embedding",
            "index": 0,
            "embedding": [
                -0.0030878915,
                0.008527344,
                0.0036363655,
                -0.05539084,
                -0.04473669,
                0.03561223,
                0.015806785,
                0.0021955732,
                -0.0052868193,
                0.011660523,
                -0.012861462,
                0.026071802,
                0.00896344,
                0.002973836,
                0.0025729635
            ]
        }
    ],
    "model": "text-embedding-ada-002-v2",
    "usage": {
        "prompt_tokens": 58,
        "total_tokens": 58
    }
}
```

I think it's clear it has something to do with the **type**, but I've been trying to get that embedding key values with no luck, so any bit of help would be very appreciate.

I tried approching this using a few alternatives:

**classic**

```
    const embedding: string = response.data;
    console.log('Result:', embedding);
```

logs:

```
Result: {
  object: 'list',
  data: [ { object: 'embedding', index: 0, embedding: [Array] } ],
  model: 'text-embedding-ada-002-v2',
  usage: { prompt_tokens: 1, total_tokens: 1 }
}
```

**The shared above
**

```
    const embedding: string = response.data[2].text;
    console.log('Result:', embedding);
```

Which gets the undefined value.

**my most desesperate attempt with no luck:
**

```
    const embedding: any = response.data[2];
    console.log('Result:', embedding);
```

Returns:

`Result: undefined`

Im expecting getting the values of the embedding array and store them in the variable embedding.

Expected output:

```
             [
                -0.0030878915,
                0.008527344,
                0.0036363655,
                -0.05539084,
                -0.04473669,
                0.03561223,
                0.015806785,
                0.0021955732,
                -0.0052868193,
                0.011660523,
                -0.012861462,
                0.026071802,
                0.00896344,
                0.002973836,
                0.0025729635
            ]
```

Variable:

```
embedding = [
                -0.0030878915,
                0.008527344,
                0.0036363655,
                -0.05539084,
                -0.04473669,
                0.03561223,
                0.015806785,
                0.0021955732,
                -0.0052868193,
                0.011660523,
                -0.012861462,
                0.026071802,
                0.00896344,
                0.002973836,
                0.0025729635
            ]
```

Will appreciate any help on this!

Comment: It looks like there is only one item in your `data` array. Therefore `2` is not a valid index and  `data[2]` will not map to anything. Try `data[0]`

Answer (score 1):

You can extract the embedding vector from the OpenAI Embeddings API endpoint response as follows:

**Python**

```
embedding = response['data'][0]['embedding']
```

**NodeJS**

```
const embedding: string = response.data[0].embedding;
```